# Django Inline Admin Formset extra entry has prefix instead of number

Tags: django, forms

I have an admin form that allows and end user to add a quiz, and the quiz has answers. When you edit the quiz, the quiz answer section has 4 lines for quiz answers. The first 3 are numbered 0, 1, 2 and the fourth is `__prefix__`.

Example:

```
<input name="quizanswer_set-0-text" value="one" class="vTextField" maxlength="255" type="text" id="id_quizanswer_set-0-text" />

<input id="id_quizanswer_set-__prefix__-text" type="text" class="vTextField" name="quizanswer_set-__prefix__-text" maxlength="255" />
```

When the form is processed, it skips the fourth input because, I'm assuming, the prefix is not what it is looking for.

Template Code:

```
{% for inline_admin_form in inline_admin_formset %}
{{ inline_admin_form.pk_field.field }} {{ inline_admin_form.fk_field.field }}
```

Form:

```
class QuizAnswerInlineFormSet(forms.models.BaseInlineFormSet):
    def is_valid(self):
        # make sure errors are populated
        _ = self.errors

        return super(QuizAnswerInlineFormSet, self).is_valid()            

    def clean(self):
        super(QuizAnswerInlineFormSet, self).clean()

        answer_count = 0
        correct_count = 0

        for form in self.forms:
            if not hasattr(form, 'cleaned_data'):
                continue
            if not form.cleaned_data:
                continue
            if not form.is_valid():
                continue
            if form.cleaned_data[forms.formsets.DELETION_FIELD_NAME]:
                continue

            answer_count += 1

            if form.cleaned_data.get("is_correct", False):
                correct_count += 1

        if answer_count < 2:
            raise ValidationError("Questions must have at least 2 answers")

        if correct_count != 1:
            raise ValidationError("There must be exactly one correct answer")
```

Does anyone have an idea of why this would be printing `__PREFIX__` rather than a number? Is there something I need to set for this? I didn't originally make the form, I'm just trying to fix it and I'm not overly familiar with this type of form.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. It turns out that row shouldn't be displayed. It is used as a template by the javascript when adding new rows and the prefix is replaced.

I found that I wasn't picking up `forms.css` properly so it couldn't find the definition for the `empty-form` class which has `display: none`.

Answer (score 0):

In my point of view **PREFIX** is used to increment the index of the rows. when we add new rows.

```html
<div class="empty-form"></div>
```

is cloned and the prefix is changed by jQuery in Admin Panel.

```
django\contrib\admin\static\admin\js\inlines.js
```

view this file. This is used for dynamic inline tabular.